# Does stack have a clear function in C++?

Tags: c++, stack

```
  stack<int> st;
  st.clear();
```

As per gfg I can do st.clear();
But I am getting

> error: 'class std::stack' has no member named 'clear'
> st.clear();

Comment: You can just abandon it, end let its life-time end which will destruct the stack and all objects in it.

Comment: Perhaps you are confusing Java with C++?

Comment: Use a more normative reference, such as cppreference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack

Comment: Short answer: If you want to be able to clear it easily, use `std::vector`, which has `push_back` and `pop_back` instead of `push` and `pop`, but works perfectly well as a stack (and can also clear itself).

Comment: @user4581301 SO succeeds in spite of itself these days. Being better != being good.

Comment: I'm not familiar with all acronyms, so what is your definition of `gfg`?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews  the OP is referring to the website geeksforgeeks